# MySQL Index is NULL but there are available Keys

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have the following problem when running a mysql query: 
Query is very slow and when i use explain the query key is null  but possible_keys are avaiable and the order is correct, i also tried adding independent indexes per each row but still key was NULL.

You can see table, index and mysql explain here: https://snag.gy/vcChl6.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer likely has just decided that there is no reason to use the index.

Since you are using `SELECT *` that means that means that if it used the index, then it would have to use the primary key from the index to then go back and look up all the necessary data from the clustered index. That is referred to as a double lookup, and is generally bad for performance. As there are so few records in this table, the optimizer likely decided that it can easily do a full table scan instead and get your result faster.

In short, this is expected behavior.

If you want to `SELECT` just some columns, add them to the `t1` index and then just `SELECT` only the columns you need, with that given `WHERE` clause. It should use the index then. As your table grows in size, it may start using the index as well, once it estimates that the double lookup is cheaper than the full table scan.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is probably it as i tried everything else to make mysql use that, i am just preparing from when the database is bigger and i wanted to pre-optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

A guess:  *Most* rows are of that 'project' and that 'lang'.

The Optimizer does not understand that fact, so it takes the index that is obviously the best:

```
(id_project, id_lang)
```

This one would be equally good:  `(id_lang, id_project)`.

No fair...  The `EXPLAIN` mentions indexes named id_project and id_lang (not useful), but the list of indexes shows a composite index `t1(id_project, id_lang)` (useful).

Then, as Willem suggests, it has to bounce between the index and the table.  Normally (that is, when it has adequate statistics), the Optimizer will say "Oh, more than ~20% of the table is being referenced; let's ignore any index."

Things you can do:

- Get rid of that index.
- Change `*` to a list of just the columns you need.  In particular, if you avoid the 3 `TEXT` columns, two optimizations kick in.  Alternatively, any that will never be longer than 255 *characters* can be changed to `VARCHAR(255)`.
- Use some other filtering, ordering, limiting, etc.  If this is a web application, do you really want to get ~534 rows?